# MYSQL - operand should contain 2 column(s)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am getting this error when I am trying to yield results based on two columns.

Here's the code :

```
@Query("select u from employee u where (u.empId, u.empRating) in (:pairs)")
List<User> getusers(List<List<String>> pairs);
```

I've tried `Map<Integer, Integer>` as well but of no avail. I've also tried converting map to string, used replaceall to construct a tuple, it didn't work either because the string has double quotes. I've checked that with the SQL as well it wasn't working when double quotes are included in the query.

Comment: yes, that is what it says! for example  "select * from user where (id, country) in ((1, "USA"), (2, "Germany))"; but it seems pairs is not represented as the two tuples that are used with in operator.

Comment: The tuple syntax you are trying to use here is unique to native MySQL, and most likely is not supported by HQL/JPA.  You will have to express your query some other way.

Comment: where (id, country) in ("(1,"USA"), (2,"Germany")"); it is oriented like this when I tried converting map to string, atleast i'm assuming. I checked it in the same link you provided, there is a syntax error you can look for yourself

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the query work with tuples. Or at least to be recognized as such. Unfortunately Hibernate 6 doesn't support tuples yet... I got a clear exception:

```
org.hibernate.NotYetImplementedFor6Exception: 
   org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.ArrayTupleType
```

My repository:

```
@Query("select c from Customer c where (c.id, c.name) in (:pairs)")
List<Customer> getCustomers(List<Map<Integer, String>> pairs);
```

Comment: it is still giving me the same error mate!